# Invoke function only if above particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that becomes 'fixed' to the bottom of the window once it is scrolled out of view. I only want this behavior when the user is viewing the top half of the page. I do not want a `fixed` state being applied to the div when the user is on the bottom part of the page.

In short - The issue I have is that a `fixed` state is being applied when the div is out of view, regardless of page position.

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19352/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (isScrolledIntoView($('#myDivWrapper'))) {
    if (!initSet) {
      initSet = true;
    }
    $("#myDiv").removeClass('fixed');
  } else if (initSet) {
    $("#myDiv").addClass('fixed');
  }
});

function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var $elem = $(elem);
  var $window = $(window);

  var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

  var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method involves editing your markup and your `isScrolledIntoView` function.

Wrap the top half (or whatever viewable area you want invoked) of your markup in a `div` give it an id of `#top`.

Modify your scroll markup as this is currently checking that ALL of the element is in view, you only want a partial check.

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19366/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if(isScrolledIntoView($('#myDivWrapper'))) {
      if (!initSet) {
        initSet = true;
      }
      $("#myDiv").removeClass('fixed');
    } else if (initSet && isScrolledIntoView($('#top'))) {
      $("#myDiv").addClass('fixed');
    }   
});

function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
  var $elem = $(elem);
  var $window = $(window);

  var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

  var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

  return  ((elemTop <= docViewBottom) && (elemBottom >= docViewTop)) ;
}
```

I would suggest modifying the isScrolledIntoView function so it accepts a second parameter/ele. This way you'd only need to call it once.

Answer (score 0):

This if block will execute only if you are on lower half of the page

```
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()/2 > $(document).height() / 2)
```

updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19370/

Comment: Thanks - the problem with this is that it only works if the top section is exactly half the page. If it's larger than half this will not work https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/19378/ I've renamed the title of the question so it isn't so literal.

Comment: Yeah, I know the flaw of the approach. I just took the title literally :)